# Telegram API call from mobile app using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, telegram

As a beginner trying to develop a messaging application using jquery mobile/phonegap app  , I wanted to  make a call to a method in the Telegram API.

Can I make a call form javascript to the telegram api? The api library is in java so how would I instantiate the object of such a library in my phone gap app since I'm not using native android or xcode for development?

Thanks so much for your time

Comment: Let me stop you right now. You are new to Stackoverflow so you can still learn. This site is not place for hot-to and advice questions. If you have a problem or error then post a question here, otherwise you should google your problem. Learn how Phonegap works and how it communicates with JavaScript. Learn to develop Android applications. Then post your problems.

Comment: Well, I thought I'll get some guidance on getting started. I did google it and went thorough various forums and the telegram api. I'll delete this question it is inappropriate.

Comment: Dont delete it, just update it with what have you done so far. Make it look like you have stuck on some problem.

Comment: Take a look here at how i got started in building my own telegram client and mroe on how to get help understanding telegram-api http://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080