# How to implement authorization using a Telegram API?

Tags: php, algorithm, api, rest, telegram

I want to implement multiple authorization using PHP for interaction with Telegram REST API.

What task am I trying to solve? Well, it's simple: several dozens of users (all of them have a carma like here (+10, -2, +1000 etc.) with relevant group taxonomy: web-masters and customers) have a user profile on my website. After they reach a certain amount of carma and since they are authorized in their profile they are joined to private chats based on Telegram generated for them automatically.

After some research, I found that it's very complicated because:

1. I've never had an experience of API implementation for hardware-binded social networks.
2. I took a look at https://core.telegram.org/api/auth, but it's completely unobvious how to implement these functions (for example auth.sendCode), using PHP or any other language. If these commands should be sent as JSON to server, then it doesn't look like JSON:

   ```
     auth.sentCode#efed51d9 phone_registered:Bool phone_code_hash:string send_call_timeout:int is_password:Bool = auth.SentCode;
   ```

   What is it? In which language is it written?

   ***UPD:*** It's written in TL (Type Language): https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/TL
3. I've explored the source code of several clients (Webogram, Telegram-cli (tg), tdesktop), and I found several implementations of https://core.telegram.org/mtproto

Unfortunately, none of them support multiple authorization on their side, and after a little bit of research, I have no idea where to dig deeper to find out more information.

Also, these implementations look bulky and compound (for example, https://github.com/vysheng/tg):
[image]

There I see bunch of servers (./tg/tgl/tgl.h):

```
#define TG_SERVER_1 "149.154.175.50"
#define TG_SERVER_2 "149.154.167.51"
#define TG_SERVER_3 "149.154.175.100"
#define TG_SERVER_4 "149.154.167.91"
#define TG_SERVER_5 "149.154.171.5"
```

I found several possibly appropriate functions (./tg/tgl/queries.c):

```
void empty_auth_file (void) {
  if (TLS->test_mode) {
    bl_do_dc_option (TLS, 1, "", 0, TG_SERVER_TEST_1, strlen (TG_SERVER_TEST_1), 443);
    bl_do_dc_option (TLS, 2, "", 0, TG_SERVER_TEST_2, strlen (TG_SERVER_TEST_2), 443);
    bl_do_dc_option (TLS, 3, "", 0, TG_SERVER_TEST_3, strlen (TG_SERVER_TEST_3), 443);
    bl_do_set_working_dc (TLS, TG_SERVER_TEST_DEFAULT);
  } else {
    bl_do_dc_option (TLS, 1, "", 0, TG_SERVER_1, strlen (TG_SERVER_1), 443);
    bl_do_dc_option (TLS, 2, "", 0, TG_SERVER_2, strlen (TG_SERVER_2), 443);
    bl_do_dc_option (TLS, 3, "", 0, TG_SERVER_3, strlen (TG_SERVER_3), 443);
    bl_do_dc_option (TLS, 4, "", 0, TG_SERVER_4, strlen (TG_SERVER_4), 443);
    bl_do_dc_option (TLS, 5, "", 0, TG_SERVER_5, strlen (TG_SERVER_5), 443);
    bl_do_set_working_dc (TLS, TG_SERVER_DEFAULT);
  }
}

void bl_do_dc_option (struct tgl_state *TLS, int id, const char *name, int l1, const char *ip, int l2, int port) {
  struct tgl_dc *DC = TLS->DC_list[id];
  if (DC && !strncmp (ip, DC->ip, l2)) { return; }

  clear_packet ();
  out_int (CODE_binlog_dc_option);
  out_int (id);
  out_cstring (name, l1);
  out_cstring (ip, l2);
  out_int (port);

  add_log_event (TLS, packet_buffer, 4 * (packet_ptr - packet_buffer));
}
```

etc.

What files should I transfer to PHP for multiple user auth implementation?
Could you please help me to know where to start from and how to make it easier than it currently is?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to connect PHP to telegram this time no success, so I will be glad if you have any improvement on this case. Plz let me know.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

So far I have been able to implement the telegram authorization completely, but not in your requested language - PHP, I used vb.Net. However, I believe the same logic should apply.

**Creating a Telegram Authorization Key**

Telegram API is no walk in the park. Studying existing src code could be quite daunting (IMHO). Hence my approach was to study the online API documentation and implement the sample-auth_key outlined in the links below.

https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/auth_key

https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/samples-auth_key

What this approach will give you is a better understanding and introduction to the primitives used throughout Telegram API, and possibly help you start organizing your own set of functions and routines to handle which you will need for the next steps - implementing other features of the API, since generating an AuthKey is just the beginning.

**Step 1**

All Communication is via TCP - Once you have obtained a unique api_id (https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id#obtaining-api-id) you will find the following IP advertised for use in testing: **149.154.167.40:433** The api_id is not required at this point for generating an AuthKey

Setup your preferred method of Send/Receive TCP processing Loop

what I have is a private SendData that simply sends a bytes to a live socket connected to the give IP address above

```vb
Private Sub SendData(b() As Byte, Optional read As Boolean = False)
    If Not IsConnected() Then
        Log("Connection Closed!", ConsoleColor.DarkRed)
        RaiseEvent Disconneted()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    b = TCPPack(b)
    
    Dim arg = New SocketAsyncEventArgs With {.RemoteEndPoint = ep}
    AddHandler arg.Completed, AddressOf IO_Handler
    arg.SetBuffer(b, 0, b.Length)
    
    Try
        If Not soc.SendAsync(arg) Then
            IO_Handler(soc, arg)
        End If
    
        If read Then
            ReadData()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
            Log("SendData: " & ex.ToString, ConsoleColor.Red)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub ReadData(Optional wait As Integer = 0)
    If Not IsConnected() Then
        Log("Connection Closed!", ConsoleColor.DarkRed)
        RaiseEvent Disconneted()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim arg = New SocketAsyncEventArgs With {.RemoteEndPoint = ep}
    AddHandler arg.Completed, AddressOf IO_Handler

    Dim b(BUFFER_SIZE - 1) As Byte
    arg.SetBuffer(b, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)

    Try
        If Not soc.ReceiveAsync(arg) Then
            IO_Handler(soc, arg)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Log("ReadMessages: " & ex.ToString, ConsoleColor.Red)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub IO_Handler(sender As Object, e As SocketAsyncEventArgs)
    Log($"{e.LastOperation}:{e.SocketError}:{e.BytesTransferred}", ConsoleColor.Cyan)

    Select Case e.SocketError
        Case SocketError.Success
            Select Case e.LastOperation
                Case SocketAsyncOperation.Connect 'A socket Connect operation.
                    Log("Connected to " & e.ConnectSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString, ConsoleColor.Green)
                    are.Set()

                    Case SocketAsyncOperation.Disconnect, SocketAsyncOperation.Connect
                        RaiseEvent Disconneted()

                Case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive 'A socket Receive operation.
                        HandleData(e)
            End Select

        Case SocketError.ConnectionAborted
                RaiseEvent Disconneted()
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub HandleData(e As SocketAsyncEventArgs)
    If e.BytesTransferred = 0 Then --no pending data
        Log("The remote end has closed the connection.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim len As Integer = e.Buffer(0)
    Dim start = 1

    If len = &H7F Then
        len = e.Buffer(1)
        len += e.Buffer(2) << 8
        len += e.Buffer(3) << 16
        start = 4
    End If

    len = 4 * len

    Dim data(len - 1) As Byte
    Array.Copy(e.Buffer, start, data, 0, len)


    ProcessResponse(data)

    ReadData()
End Sub
```

Finally for this step, we need a TcpPack() method which helps us pad our data in the format Telegram expects - see code below with comments

```vb
Private Function TCPPack(b As Byte()) As Byte()
    Dim a = New List(Of Byte)
    Dim len = CByte(b.Length / 4)

    If efSent = False Then --TCP abridged version
        efSent = True
        a.Add(&HEF)
    End If

    If len >= &H7F Then
        a.Add(&H7F)
        a.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(len))
    Else
        a.Add(len)
    End If

    a.AddRange(b) --only data, no sequence number, no CRC32

    Return a.ToArray
End Function
```

**STEP 2**

With the basic TCP send/receive routines setup, we can start preparing data packets to send to telegram and have sub routines for handling the specific responses received - **ProcessResponse(data)**

What we need to understand next is the fact that Telegram handles 2 broad categories of messages -

*Unencrypted* - https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description#unencrypted-message

These are plain text messages with their `auth_key_id =0` generating an AuthKey uses this type of message throughout

*Encrypted* - https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description#encrypted-message-encrypted-data

All further communication with Telegram Servers will be via encrypted messages

I choose to have two classes to encapsulate both message types. I can then have two Send(m) methods that handles each type

```vb
Private Sub Send(m As UnencryptedMessage)
    Log(m.ToString, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, logTime:=False)
    SendData(m.data, True)
End Sub

Private Sub Send(m As EncryptedMessage)
    Log(m.ToString, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, logTime:=False)
    SendData(m.data, True)
End Sub
```

For now only **UnencryptedMessage** is required

```vb
Public Class UnencryptedMessage
    Public Property auth_key_id As Int64
    Public Property message_id As Int64
    Public Property data_length As Int32
    Public Property message_data As Byte()
    Public Property message_type As String
    Public Property data As Byte() = {}
    
    Sub New(auth_key As Int64, message_id As Int64, data As Byte())
        _auth_key_id = auth_key
        _message_id = message_id
        _data_length = data.Length
        _message_data = data
        message_type = B2Hr(data, 0, 4)
    
        Dim a = New List(Of Byte)
    
        a.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(auth_key_id)) --{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        a.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(message_id))
        a.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(data_length))
        a.AddRange(message_data)
    
        Me.data = a.ToArray
    End Sub
    
    Sub New(b As Byte())
        data = b
    
        Dim skip = 0
    
        _auth_key_id = BitConverter.ToInt64(b, skip) : skip += 8
        _message_id = BitConverter.ToInt64(b, skip) : skip += 8
        _data_length = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, skip) : skip += 4
    
        ReDim _message_data(_data_length - 1)
    
        Array.Copy(b, skip, _message_data, 0, b.Length - skip)
    
        message_type = B2Hr(_message_data, 0, 4)
    End Sub
    
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return $"
        raw_data: {B2H(data)}
     auth_key_id: {i2H(auth_key_id)}  {auth_key_id}
      message_id: {i2H(message_id)}  {message_id}
     data_length: {i2H(data_length)}  {data_length}
    message_data: {B2H(message_data)}
    message_type: {message_type}
    "
    End Function
End Class
```

**STEP 3**

Now we follow he series of steps outlined in  https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/auth_key

- https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/auth_key#dh-exchange-initiation

> 1. Client sends query to server
>
> req_pq#60469778 nonce:int128 = ResPQ The value of nonce is selected
> randomly by the client (random number) and identifies the client
> within this communication. Following this step, it is known to all.
>
> 2. Server sends response of the form
>
> resPQ#05162463 nonce:int128 server_nonce:int128 pq:string
> server_public_key_fingerprints:Vector long = ResPQ

My approach for this is very simple:

```
Sub RequestPQAuthorization()
    Send(MTProto.req_pq)
End Sub
```

In a Class called MTProto I implement a set of shared functions as required by each step of the exchange. Each method is simply building up an Encrypted data structure which will be sent as above where required

We start with: **req_pq**

```vb
Shared Function req_pq(Optional nonce As Byte() = Nothing) As UnencryptedMessage
    --req_pq#60469778 
    --nonce:int128
    If nonce Is Nothing Then
        ReDim nonce(15)
        RND.NextBytes(nonce)
    End If

    Dim d = New List(Of Byte)
    d.AddRange({120, 151, 70, 96}) --60469778
    d.AddRange(nonce)

    Return New UnencryptedMessage(0, CreateMessageId, d.ToArray)
End Function

Private Shared Function CreateMessageId() As Int64
    Return CLng((Date.UtcNow.Ticks - ZERO_TICK) * 429.4967296)
End Function
```

Public Const ZERO_TICK = 621355968000000000 -- i.e. 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (January 1, 1970, at 12:00 AM UTC)

Now our process response method from **Step 1**

```vb
Private Sub ProcessResponse(data As Byte())
    Try
        Dim r = New UnencryptedMessage(data)
        Log(r.ToString, ConsoleColor.Yellow, logTime:=False)

        Select Case r.message_type
            Case resPQ.Classid
                RequestDHKeyExchange(New resPQ(r.message_data))
            Case server_DH_params_ok.Classid
                RequestSetDH_params(New server_DH_params_ok(r.message_data), new_nonce)
            Case server_DH_params_fail.Classid
                Log(New server_DH_params_fail(r.message_data).ToString, ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta)
            Case dh_gen_ok.Classid
                Log(New dh_gen_ok(r.message_data).ToString, ConsoleColor.Green)
            Case dh_gen_retry.Classid
                Log(New dh_gen_retry(r.message_data).ToString, ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta)
            Case dh_gen_fail.Classid
                Log(New dh_gen_fail(r.message_data).ToString, ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta)
            Case Else
                Log($"Unhandled type: {r.message_type}", ConsoleColor.Magenta)
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        Log($"Error: {ex.ToString}", ConsoleColor.Red)
        Log(B2H(data), ConsoleColor.DarkRed, logTime:=False)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Great so far, each response received has a message_type code.

we can switch on that and determine how each is handled. We need to process resPQ right now.

What i have done is to create a a set of classes that each handles a specific response type

```vb
''' <summary>
''' resPQ#05162463 
''' nonce:int128 server_nonce:int128 pq:string server_public_key_fingerprints:Vector long = ResPQ
''' </summary>
Public NotInheritable Class resPQ : Inherits TLObject
    Public Shared Shadows ReadOnly Property Classid As String = "05162463"
    Public Property nonce As Byte()
    Public Property server_nonce As Byte()
    Public Property pq As Byte()
    Public Property fingerprints As List(Of UInt64)
    Public Property count As Int32

    Sub New(data As Byte())
        Dim skip = 4
        nonce = Slice(data, skip, 16) : skip += 16
        server_nonce = Slice(data, skip, 16) : skip += 16
        skip += 1 'length of pq:string
        pq = Slice(data, skip, 8) : skip += 8
        skip += 3 'padding to complete the 4-bytes
        skip += 4 '%(Vector long) 1cb5c415
        count = i32r(data, skip) : skip += 4

        fingerprints = New List(Of UInt64)

        For i = 0 To count - 1
            fingerprints.Add(u64r(data, skip))
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"
     classid: {NameOf(resPQ)}#{Classid}
       nonce: {B2H(nonce)}
server_nonce: {B2H(server_nonce)}
          pq: {B2H(pq)}  {u64(pq)}
       count: {i2H(count)}  {count}
fingerprints: {i2H(fingerprints(0))}  {fingerprints(0)}
"
    End Function
End Class
```

Each is based on this simple object

```vb
Public MustInherit Class TLObject
    Public Shared Property ClassId As String
    Public MustOverride Overrides Function ToString() As String
End Class
```

Building on this, we tackle steps 3 & 4

> Proof of work 3) Client decomposes pq into prime factors such that p <
> q.
>
> This starts a round of Diffie-Hellman key exchanges.
>
> Presenting proof of work; Server authentication 4) Client sends query
> to server
>
> req_DH_params#d712e4be nonce:int128 server_nonce:int128 p:string
> q:string public_key_fingerprint:long encrypted_data:string =
> Server_DH_Params

This is initiated  here `RequestDHKeyExchange(New resPQ(r.message_data))` in my `ProcessResponse` routine above

```vb
Sub RequestDHKeyExchange(r As resPQ)
    Log(r.ToString, ConsoleColor.Gray, logTime:=False)

    'decompose prime cofactors
    Dim pp = New PrimeProduct(r.pq)
    Log(pp.ToString, ConsoleColor.Gray, logTime:=False)

    'encrypted_data Generation
    Dim pq = New P_Q_inner_data(r.pq, pp.p, pp.q, r.nonce, r.server_nonce)
    new_nonce = pq.new_nonce

    'The serialization Of P_Q_inner_data produces some String data. This Is followed by encrypted_data
    'data_with_hash := SHA1(data) + data + (any random bytes); such that the length equal 255 
    Dim data_with_hash = New List(Of Byte)

    'SHA1(data) = xxx- 40 =20 bytes
    Using sha1 = New SHA1Managed
        Dim b = pq.ToBytes
        data_with_hash.AddRange(sha1.ComputeHash(b))
        data_with_hash.AddRange(b)
    End Using

    If data_with_hash.Count < 255 Then
        Dim pad(255 - data_with_hash.Count - 1) As Byte
        RND.NextBytes(pad)
        data_with_hash.AddRange(pad)
    End If

    'RSA(data_with_hash, server_public_key) = xxx - 512 = 256 bytes
    Dim key = i2H(r.fingerprints(0)) 'c3b42b026ce86b21
    Dim zb = Crypto.rsaEncrypt(data_with_hash.ToArray, key)
    Send(MTProto.req_DH_params(r.nonce, r.server_nonce, pp.p, pp.q, r.fingerprints(0), zb))
End Sub
```

You can use your own implementation of Prime-Decomposition to replace this line `Dim pp = New PrimeProduct(r.pq)`

Here is an example of how I learnt do it using **PollardBrent** (Pollard Rho Brent Integer Factorization) https://stackoverflow.com/a/31978350/44080

Okay if you can follow up to this point you have a general idea of how i'm decomposing the AuthKey implementation step by step.

You should be able to run through the remaining steps 5-9. It's a lot for me to type...

If this answer so far is of any help to anyone, then i'll take out time to organize and post the remaining part.

I believe that the routines and knowledge you build up along the way should give you the tools you need to both understand and implement your own independent Telegram API code from scratch.

**Completed Interaction Dump**

```
03:33:26.591  Connect:Success:0
03:33:26.593  Connected to 149.154.167.40:443
03:33:26.598
    raw_data: 000000000000000000DC799836FE075614000000789746604479257F6C01C039A3DEAD031BC2D6A4
 auth_key_id: 0000000000000000  0
  message_id: 5607FE369879DC00  6199202922538589184
 data_length: 00000014  20
message_data: 789746604479257F6C01C039A3DEAD031BC2D6A4
message_type: 60469778

03:33:26.600  Send:Success:42
03:33:26.735  Receive:Success:85
03:33:26.737
    raw_data: 0000000000000000015CF64539FE075640000000632416054479257F6C01C039A3DEAD031BC2D6A44F9DB065B36308CF4D9965725DD7153D0818DDCAF407B7CDCD00000015C4B51C01000000216BE86C022BB4C3
 auth_key_id: 0000000000000000  0
  message_id: 5607FE3945F65C01  6199202934039141377
 data_length: 00000040  64
message_data: 632416054479257F6C01C039A3DEAD031BC2D6A44F9DB065B36308CF4D9965725DD7153D0818DDCAF407B7CDCD00000015C4B51C01000000216BE86C022BB4C3
message_type: 05162463

03:33:26.743
     classid: resPQ#05162463
       nonce: 4479257F6C01C039A3DEAD031BC2D6A4
server_nonce: 4F9DB065B36308CF4D9965725DD7153D
          pq: 18DDCAF407B7CDCD  1791811376213642701
       count: 00000001  1
fingerprints: C3B42B026CE86B21  14101943622620965665

03:33:26.810
PQ: 18DDCAF407B7CDCD  1791811376213642701
 P: 45F57B87  1173715847
 Q: 5AFE490B  1526614283

03:33:26.930
    raw_data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
 auth_key_id: 0000000000000000  0
  message_id: 5607FE36EE3C4000  6199202923977392128
 data_length: 00000140  320
message_data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
message_type: D712E4BE

03:33:26.933  Send:Success:341
03:33:27.217  Receive:Success:656
03:33:27.217
    raw_data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
 auth_key_id: 0000000000000000  0
  message_id: 5607FE399F9A1C01  6199202935543045121
 data_length: 00000278  632
message_data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
message_type: D0E8075C

03:33:27.240
     classid: server_DH_params_ok#D0E8075C
       nonce: 4479257F6C01C039A3DEAD031BC2D6A4
server_nonce: 4F9DB065B36308CF4D9965725DD7153D
  enc_answer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

tmp_aes_key: 297CB750FF0052B67515B3F11B45F11F15D106BC25ED0027570D5B9D83102BFA
 tmp_aes_iv: CBDCF40A77B6A1C7CE74A1F8EC8E091A49FAD3B9A2499BFFFD084D537A53B36D
     answer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

     classid: Server_DH_inner_data#B5890DBA
       nonce: 4479257F6C01C039A3DEAD031BC2D6A4
server_nonce: 4F9DB065B36308CF4D9965725DD7153D
           g: 00000003  3
    dh_prime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
         g_a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
 server_time: 5607FE39  1443364409
 client_time: 5607FE37  1443364407
     padding: 646CF781176C3EAC

DH_Prime is Safe? = True

     classid: Client_DH_Inner_Data#6643B654
       nonce: 4479257F6C01C039A3DEAD031BC2D6A4
server_nonce: 4F9DB065B36308CF4D9965725DD7153D
    retry_id: 0000000000000000  0
         g_b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

03:33:27.590  enc_data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
03:33:27.810  auth_Key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
03:33:27.813
    raw_data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
 auth_key_id: 0000000000000000  0
  message_id: 5607FE37D0489C00  6199202927769852928
 data_length: 00000178  376
message_data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
message_type: F5045F1F

03:33:27.823  Send:Success:397
03:33:27.983  Receive:Success:73
03:33:27.985
```

....

Regards.

Comment: I actually upvoted your answer. But I wish many things. I wish you would use a more globally recognized language (at least from C family) to make your code more familiar and readable for people who seed an answer. Also I wish Telegram's API would be more easy to learn and implement. It seems that it has a big learning curve.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati sorry man, vb.net comes naturally to me. Yes, telegram's documentation is hard. It takes some work to get through.

Comment: @RezaSh hi, i'm not done yet. Been busy with other things at the moment. but i can publish the AuthKey Generation which is complete. I'll find time to upload it to Github

Comment: Your example not with PHP, question author asked PHP example. I can't understand VB code too.

Comment: So this guide has been very, very useful for me but I still can't communicate with the server. I'm using .net framework and my program can successfully genarate the 40-byte message, but as I send it via my socket, I recieve zeroes from the server. So I think it might be caused by improper socket configuration (I used SocketType.Stream and ProtocolType.Tcp). Could you post the whole code or tell us how to send bytes to telegram server (ie what socket configuration?). A Github link would be awesome too.

Comment: @mostafa-farzán please make this a new question. So it does not distract from this answer, and we can focus on the network aspect

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu, you're right. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660162/how-to-send-valid-tcp-messages-to-a-telegram-server-on-net-framework

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu thanks man things are far more clear now tg api documentation sucks

Comment: Maybe a well-known language like C family languages or python could be a better choice. anyway thank you

Comment: this is better than telegram official documentation, but can someone give me the code to a simple language like javascript / python / dart, I don't understand what code language this is

Answer (score 11):

I have written a PHP implementation of mtproto, and so far I have managed to implement TL serialization/deserialization, tcp abridged/intermediate/full connections, http/https connections.

I have implemented OOP wrappers for all mtproto methods, a prime generation module based on Python/wolfram alpha/php, HTML/Markdown parsing with support for mentions, bot API file id support, update handling with callbacks or getupdates, bot API <-> MTProto object conversion, upload/download wrappers, login wrappers for bots/users (2FA is supported), simple error handling, internal peer management (you can provide a simple bot API chat id, a username or a peer id in tg-cli format to send a message or to call other mtproto methods) and I am currently working on a nice Lua wrapper to allow usage of td-cli/tg-cli bots w/ MadelineProto.

I have also written a class to generate documentation for all mtproto methods/constructors/types (available at https://daniil.it/MadelineProto/API_docs).
MadelineProto can be serialized to a file to allow easy session storage.

If anyone is interested, or wants to contribute, here is the link to the github repo: https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto

Comment: It's the only implementation. I'm going to give it a try :)

Answer (score 4):

As a follow up to my original post, once you are done with the auth_key steps the following will be useful to quickly get you up to speed with how the rest of telegram works.

1) Download and study the source code for [Webogram](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram), it is all basically JavaScript.

2) run a local copy of Webogram modified with console.logs to clearly show you step by step the interactions that are taking place between "a working telegram client" and the telegram servers. This will give you a work-flow of how telegram clients and Telegram really work.

3) Use whatever development language you are most comfortable with to build your own implementation of a Protocol Parser for converting binary streams into TL types and vice-versa

*It's actually quite fun to code this step. I've just built a simple Protocol Parser in **[Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/)***

4) Here is a sample log from a modified copy of Webogram.

It shows what steps to take after successfully generated your Auth_key

You even get to see where it has to generate a new Auth_key in-flight as it switches the validated your to the proper DataCenter, recreating his session, new server_salts etc (not shown)

Regards.

```
ID  time    info    log
121 12:26:35.318    new Auth    Auth successfull! dc= 2 mtproto.js:479:15
127 12:26:35.325    CALL    =>> API call help.getNearestDc Object {  } Object { dcID: 2, createNetworker: true } mtproto.js:749:4
128 12:26:35.327    enc-START   [invokeWithLayer] 45 mtproto.js:753:7
168 12:26:35.551    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.51/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 708ms]
189 12:26:36.522    msg-r   <<=m [msg_container] Object { _: "msg_container", messages: Array[2] } mtproto.js:1452:5
190 12:26:36.523    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200678614200321", seqno: 1, bytes: 28, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
191 12:26:36.525    msg-r   <<=m [new_session_created] Object { _: "new_session_created", first_msg_id: "6242200671500883244", unique_id: "645797764649391412", server_salt: "17212767594123551779" } mtproto.js:1452:5
192 12:26:36.526    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200678630513665", seqno: 3, bytes: 28, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
193 12:26:36.528    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200671500883244", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
257 12:26:39.239    new Auth    Auth successfull! dc= 4 mtproto.js:479:15
270 12:26:59.606    CALL    =>> API call auth.sendCode Object { phone_number: "2348022002298", sms_type: 5, api_id: 38665, api_hash: "880c7847a517fc455d7d54731e90ad4e", lang_code: "en-US" } Object { dcID: 2, createNetworker: true } mtproto.js:749:4
321 12:27:00.048    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.51/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 422ms]
328 12:27:00.981    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200779464550396", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
331 12:27:00.986    CALL    =>> API call auth.sendCode Object { phone_number: "2348022002298", sms_type: 5, api_id: 38665, api_hash: "880c7847a517fc455d7d54731e90ad4e", lang_code: "en-US" } Object { dcID: "4", createNetworker: true, resultType: "auth.SentCode", messageID: "6242200779464550396" } mtproto.js:749:4
332 12:27:00.987    enc-START   [invokeWithLayer] 45 mtproto.js:753:7
377 12:27:01.288    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 321ms]
398 12:27:02.170    msg-r   <<=m [msg_container] Object { _: "msg_container", messages: Array[2] } mtproto.js:1452:5
399 12:27:02.171    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200787684582401", seqno: 1, bytes: 28, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
400 12:27:02.172    msg-r   <<=m [new_session_created] Object { _: "new_session_created", first_msg_id: "6242200784556418516", unique_id: "13396961033572361155", server_salt: "7076519506215495914" } mtproto.js:1452:5
401 12:27:02.173    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200787775901697", seqno: 3, bytes: 48, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
402 12:27:02.174    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200784556418516", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
407 12:27:02.344    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25154ms]
414 12:27:03.068    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200779464550396" } mtproto.js:1452:5
420 12:27:15.639    CALL    =>> API call auth.sendSms Object { phone_number: "2348022002298", phone_code_hash: "696b5befd8e809de81" } Object { dcID: "4", createNetworker: true, resultType: "auth.SentCode", messageID: "6242200784556418516" } mtproto.js:749:4
468 12:27:15.924    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 457ms]
475 12:27:17.154    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200848242727644", result: true } mtproto.js:1452:5
482 12:27:27.511    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200848242727644" } mtproto.js:1452:5
505 12:27:31.003    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.51/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25161ms]
511 12:27:40.133    CALL    =>> API call auth.signIn Object { phone_number: "2348022002298", phone_code_hash: "696b5befd8e809de81", phone_code: "26914" } Object { dcID: "4", createNetworker: true, resultType: "Bool", messageID: "6242200848242727644" } mtproto.js:749:4
560 12:27:40.454    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 756ms]
567 12:27:41.223    msg-r   <<=m [msg_container] Object { _: "msg_container", messages: Array[2] } mtproto.js:1452:5
568 12:27:41.224    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200956100910081", seqno: 7, bytes: 80, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
569 12:27:41.225    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200954555850604", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
570 12:27:41.226    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200956751929345", seqno: 9, bytes: 88, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
571 12:27:41.227    msg-r   <<=m [updates] Object { _: "updates", updates: Array[1], users: Array[0], chats: Array[0], date: 1453375666, seq: 2 } mtproto.js:1452:5
579 12:27:41.758    CALL    =>> API call updates.getState Object {  } Object { noErrorBox: true } mtproto.js:749:4
586 12:27:41.842    CALL    =>> API call account.updateStatus Object { offline: false } Object { noErrorBox: true } mtproto.js:749:4
594 12:27:41.850    CALL    =>> API call messages.getDialogs Object { offset_date: 0, offset_id: 0, offset_peer: Object, limit: 20 } Object { timeout: 300 } mtproto.js:749:4
655 12:27:42.965    CALL    =>> API call messages.getAllStickers Object { hash: "" } Object {  } mtproto.js:749:4
696 12:27:43.920    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 908ms]
712 12:27:44.613    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 303ms]
727 12:27:46.488    msg-r   <<=m [msg_container] Object { _: "msg_container", messages: Array[3] } mtproto.js:1452:5
728 12:27:46.489    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970862778369", seqno: 11, bytes: 36, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
729 12:27:46.489    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960159395644", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
730 12:27:46.490    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970891641857", seqno: 13, bytes: 776, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
731 12:27:46.492    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960356118244", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
732 12:27:46.494    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970897958913", seqno: 15, bytes: 16, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
733 12:27:46.495    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960337591900", result: true } mtproto.js:1452:5
740 12:27:46.567    msg-r   <<=m [msg_container] Object { _: "msg_container", messages: Array[4] } mtproto.js:1452:5
741 12:27:46.568    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970862778369", seqno: 11, bytes: 36, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
742 12:27:46.569    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960159395644" } mtproto.js:1452:5
743 12:27:46.569    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970891641857", seqno: 13, bytes: 776, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
744 12:27:46.570    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960356118244" } mtproto.js:1452:5
745 12:27:46.571    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200970897958913", seqno: 15, bytes: 16, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
746 12:27:46.572    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200960337591900" } mtproto.js:1452:5
747 12:27:46.573    msg-r   <<=m [message] Object { _: "message", msg_id: "6242200973791209473", seqno: 17, bytes: 76, body: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
748 12:27:46.574    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200964892679524", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
754 12:27:46.584    CALL    =>> API call messages.getStickerSet Object { stickerset: Object } Object {  } mtproto.js:749:4
811 12:27:47.346    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 539ms]
818 12:27:48.175    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242200981275507620", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
857 12:27:49.351    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25141ms]
864 12:27:57.219    msg-r   <<=m [msgs_ack] Object { _: "msgs_ack", msg_ids: Array[0] } mtproto.js:1452:5
870 12:28:04.673    CALL    =>> API call messages.readHistory Object { peer: Object, max_id: 0 } Object {  } mtproto.js:749:4
908 12:28:04.860    CALL    =>> API call messages.getHistory Object { peer: Object, offset_id: 16, add_offset: 0, limit: 20 } Object { timeout: 300, noErrorBox: true } mtproto.js:749:4
922 12:28:05.713    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 367ms]
929 12:28:06.096    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242201058769372356", result: Object } mtproto.js:1452:5
936 12:28:15.702    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242201058769372356" } mtproto.js:1452:5
977 12:28:16.122    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25170ms]
983 12:28:26.637    CALL    =>> API call account.updateStatus Object { offline: true } Object { noErrorBox: true } mtproto.js:749:4
1016    12:28:26.660    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 302ms]
1023    12:28:27.062    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242201153183272948", result: true } mtproto.js:1452:5
1030    12:28:41.985    msg-r   <<=m [rpc_result] Object { _: "rpc_result", req_msg_id: "6242201153183272948" } mtproto.js:1452:5
1071    12:28:42.421    SEND    POST XHR http://149.154.167.91/apiw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25165ms]
```

Answer (score 0):

As of February'2018 you can use an official [Telegram Login Widget](https://telegram.org/blog/login) on your website.