# How To Download Or Implement Telegram API Into My App

Tags: android, eclipse, api, telegram

I'm Currently Writing An Android Application Using ECLIPSE.
I Want To Use Telegram API In My Application Because My Application Will Send An Static Message To An Static Number On Telegram.

I've Been Downloaded Telegram Sample API On [TELEGRAM API ON GitHub](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjACahUKEwiCvPaV3I_GAhUpw3IKHULHBL0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FDrKLO%2FTelegram&ei=RLt9VYKKLamGywPCjpPoCw&usg=AFQjCNFaA8eWofdrj_53U_AwwmN7hMESRg&sig2=GzS_AtNf9SRpO5RrwBX3Ew&bvm=bv.95515949,d.bGQ) And Import In Into ECLIPSE ... But I Can't Find Any API Or Code Which Can Be Reusable ...

Please Guide Me Into Correct API Or A Way To Implement Into My App ...

Also I Registered My Application on Telegram Core Website And Gave My App HASH Code And Authentication Code Too.

Comment: you can get started with these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080

Comment: You can use a library written in C# language called TLSharp: https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp