# Does plain sms or mms (not iMessage) support group messaging?

Tags: android, ios, sms, mms

I've noticed that group sms sent via iphone to android and ios users behave differently.

Whereas iMessage retains the group conversation, the android recipients end up having one on one conversations with the sender and not seeing the group responses or the group recipients list.

Does sms natively support group/cc, if not are there any suggested workarounds if say we only need to support ios and android users, perhaps with something in Android as well that'll let group messages be compatible between android and ios?

Comment: It seems that SMS does not support group messaging. I  think it has to be an MMS rather than an SMS message, but I'm not positive, so I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer. If that's the case the solution to supporting Android would be to use MMS rather than SMS for group messages.

Comment: googling around it does seem like mms might support it - but haven't found any definitive docs at twilio or anywhere else yet

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "group SMS". SMS, by definition, is limited to a single recipient and limited in both total size (message plus overhead) and message size. SMS messages are delivered quickly because they are carried as part of the same small housekeeping traffic which is constantly being exchanged between your handset and nearby cell towers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service

Any app which claims to do things like group SMS or expanded message size is really using some technology other than SMS; either MMS or some other data-centric mode.

The only other thing I can think of would be to try to use a cross platform messaging app's APIs (something like Telegram?) to provide the functionality. See [How to interact with Telegram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228368/how-to-interact-with-telegram-api) for more details.