# is teleram core API based on http request?

Tags: api, telegram, core-api

I am trying to get to know that how the Telegram API is working. I read the BOT API and i realized its based on HTTP requests.

I am wondering if the core API of telegram is the same, or not?

A simple explanation of how it's working would be a big help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telegram API offers a means of communicating securely with Telegram's Servers.

You may use either [TCP, UDP or HTTP Transports](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto#transport).

To help you get started check out these few posts:

[How to implement authorization using a Telegram API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661644/how-to-implement-authorization-using-a-telegram-api/32809138#32809138)

[How to interact with Telegram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228368/how-to-interact-with-telegram-api/32809368#32809368)

Hope this helps.