# How to specify and implement Telegram API methods in Requests?

Tags: api, post, telegram, mtproto

I am trying simply connect to Telegram API servers and get response.
I've create a app in my.telegram.org, Now I have my api_id, api_hash and also IP address to Telegram api MTproto serever. for getting start [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api/auth) says we have to Authorize first using [auth.sendCode](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode) method to send a code to api user's phone.

so I tried this python script to use auth.sendCode method:

```
q="auth.sendCode \"phone_number\" 0 api_id \"api_hash\" \"en\""

res = requests.post("http://149.154.167.50:443",data=q)
```

and when I print res, it says Response [404]. according to the documentation it means An attempt to invoke a non-existent object, such as a method.

I am sure the problem is about my data field in post request. the string I made for calling auth.sendCode method is wrong so server can't recognize what I am trying to reach to.

there is a Query example for that method in documentation :

(auth.sendCode "79991234567" 1 32 "test-hash" "en")

please someone helps me to correct that data string (according to this example). how can I implement API methods in Post Requests?

Answer (score 1):

First steps: Understand how to generate a Telegram AuthKey.

That exercise will help you build up the the basic knowledge need to move tackle Telegram API (and the rest API documentation) on your own.

For starters, i have outlined some of the basics in [this SO Post (using vb.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080)