# AbsApiState implementations for Telegram api in JAVA

Tags: java, telegram

could some one give me an example of  **AbsApiState implementations** for using in **telegram api** in **JAVA** :>please<:

finally i want to send message from one phone number to another programmatically with JAVA.

I did  google research a lot but i didn't understand life cycle of telegram api?!

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at what Webogram does. It is mainly written in javascript.

Then see if you can follow the steps here to:

1) get your APP_ID

2) write your code to obtain a valid Auth_key as indicated in the telegram API

see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080

3) check out the console.logs from a local copy of Webogram running in your browser to understand how a working client interacts with telegram servers.

4) build your parser to handle encoding and decoding of Telegrams TL types. You will need this handle messaging with the telegram servers.

5) study the MtProto encryption requirements, read and implement each step carefully, compare with what webogram logs are telling you, as well as what webogram mtProto.js is doing

That's one way to get started

cheers.