# Getting started with the Telegram API: Any useful resource?

Tags: android, api, documentation, messaging, telegram

there are already some threads on the class Telegram API, but none was really helpful.

I'm currently trying to implement it in an Android app in order to send messages through Telegram. The documentation they provide is close to incomprehensible, so do you know any good resource or guide on the API?

It seems to be necessary to instanciate TelegramApi. But this class isn't even included in the telegram .jar archive.

Does anyone have a tip on how to get started with the implementation?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try our friend [Google](https://www.google.com.lb/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=RrvVVbLzCMGSsgHjy5y4Bg#q=+android+Telegram+API++tutorial)

Comment: Sure. But even he couldn't tell me much today...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get stared you need to first implement Telegram AuthKey.

The documentation you need is here:

https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/auth_key

and here

https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/samples-auth_key

What this gives you is a starting point into understanding the documentation writing style for Telegram API, as well as a grasp of the basic patterns for interacting with Telegram-API

I had put together a detailed write up on the process i took here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080

What you should aim at is first Successfully getting your Telegram AuthKey, understanding the data you are sending and the structure of what you are receiving back.

The procedures and patterns you build along the way will be usable for further exploration of the Telegram API