# How to make a RPC call to telegram api?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rpc, telegram

More than 1 week I am trying to communicate with Telegram using RPC call. I readed more than 20 webpage in SO a telegram RPC call documentation to be able to do that, but still I can not. I need your help for this. I imported `tl-core` and `mtproto` an telegram api from github source codes into eclipse, but there are some errors that I can not solve. If anyone implemented such a app please help me about that. I need that. Thanks.

Comment: have you made any headway?

Comment: no idea for start point.

Answer (score 1):

Telegram API documentation is tricky, but once you get the hang of the authors writing style and work through the **AuthKey** Creation you will be well on your way.

The starting point in the documentation is:

https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/auth_key

and

https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/samples-auth_key

I had put together a detailed write up for most of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080)

The procedures and patterns you build along the way will be usable for further exploration of the Telegram API

cheers.