# how to use telegram API codes?

Tags: telegram

i registered in https://my.telegram.org/apps and got api_hash and api_id and public key ,now i want to use this function https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode

```
auth.sentCode#efed51d9 phone_registered:Bool phone_code_hash:string send_call_timeout:int is_password:Bool = auth.SentCode;
auth.sentAppCode#e325edcf phone_registered:Bool phone_code_hash:string send_call_timeout:int is_password:Bool = auth.SentCode;
---functions---
auth.sendCode#768d5f4d phone_number:string sms_type:int api_id:int api_hash:string lang_code:string = auth.SentCode;
```

### Query example

```
(auth.sendCode "79991234567" 1 32 "test-hash" "en")
=
(auth.sentCode
  phone_registered:(boolFalse)
  phone_code_hash:"2dc02d2cda9e615c84"
)

d16ff372 3939370b 33323139 37363534 00000001 00000020 73657409 61682d74 00006873 e77e812d
=
2215bcbd bc799737 63643212 32643230 39616463 35313665 00343863 e12b7901
```

**how can i use this query example?**

and what is this binaries? ==> "`d16ff372 3939370b 33323139` ...."

Comment: Start from generating your AuthKey. see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly start to send queries to Telegram. Creating api_hash and api_id is a basic step to start with Telegram API. Hope you know that Telegram uses its own protocol called 'MTProto'. You can get the detailed discription in Telegram's official website.

As per Telegram Protocol, the Client and Server shares the 'Authorization Key' (which is used for encryption and decryption) using Diffie-Hellman algorithm. For sample please see https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/samples-auth_key. After creating the authorization key successfully, we can start to call Telegram APIs which is called as RPC queries.

You can also refer https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api for implementation.

The hexadecimal data in the example is nothing but the query made by following the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from making a valid Telegram AuthKey.

The patterns and functions you build up along the way while doing this will help you towards building the rest of your Telegram API.

You can start with this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080

And them work up, step by step until you have the AuthKey as described in these links

https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/auth_key

https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/samples-auth_key

Part of the problem you will initially face is the documentation.

Working through this step by step and getting familiar with the authors writing style is a big help too.