# How to make a query to Telegram API in cmd or bash

Tags: tcp, telegram, mtproto

One of the first steps to start using the API is [this](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode). I have MTProto server (149.154.167.40:443), phone number, api id, hash...

How do I exactly do it? How do I make such a query? I sooo don't get it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two classes of MTProto methods: Encrypted and Plain.

Before you can start sending encrypted messages you need a valid session (and server salt) in one of Telegram's DCs (Data Centers).

To create a valid session, you need to go through the process of creating an Auth-Key. Going through this process will get you started on how to communicate with the Telegram Server.

All the examples linked below communicate with Telegram Servers via TCP

1. Obtain your API Keys as outlined here
   https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id
2. You need to perform the basic Auth-key creation as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661644/how-to-implement-authorization-using-a-telegram-api/32809138#32809138), this gives you your initial Session & Server_Salt
3. Next you complete these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35492833/44080)
4. You can now properly send the request you attempted in the sample code

`msg = TL.invokewithlayer(@layer, TL.initconnection(@app_id, @device_model, @system_version, @app_version, @lang_code, TL.help_getnearestdc))`

**MTProto format is:** `auth_id + msg_key + enc_payload`

```
enc_payload = AES_IGE_enc(payload)

payload = salt + session_id + msg_id + seq_no + len(msg) + msg + padding
```

You can get the above from [here](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description#schematic-presentation-of-messages)