# Windev Mobile - Integrate Telegram API in my main App for sending messages regarding updates

Tags: android, ios, telegram, windev

We are developing a Android App for education institutes.

This app is developed in WinDev Mobile.

This app will be distribute to multiple institutes once completed.

In this app we want to send Homework information to students and their parents using Telegram API so that they will receive the necessary information on the Telegram app installed on their Smart Phones.

For achieving this I studied the documentation of Telegram API but after reading it, what I understand is that we have to create new App ID for each different mobile phone we deploy this app on.

Did I understand this correctly?

Secondly as I am not able to understand as to how I should call the API of Telegram from my Android App. The documentation show API usage sample code in C/C++ so I am finding it hard to understand as to how I can call an API from my Android App?

Please help me.

TIA

Yogi Yang

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you:

- first try to understand the telegram API
- build a working telegram client which you can host on your server
- build and host a HTTP service that enables you to send and receive messages to your hosted telegram client
- Your android app an then utilize this HTTP service to interact with Telegram via your hosted telegram client

If you use c#, you can try this telegram library for starters:

https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp

Otherwise here are some first steps to help you get started with telegram api coding: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080

Regards.