# How Use Telegram Api in C# WIth SharpTelegram

Tags: c#, api, telegram

How Use Telegram API in C# With SharpTelegram 
i use this https://github.com/Everbytes/SharpTL
seed message to phone number have telegram in c#
i need sample use of this lib tanx

Comment: The SharpTL lib is for serialization/deserialization only. There are SharpMTProto+SharpTelegram libs in frozen undone state.

Comment: @AlexanderLogger that's why the best bet is to understand how Telegram works, write your own library and adapt it as Telegram adds new features. Once you get the basics down... its pretty straight forward

Comment: @CharlesO may be, but at least serializer is done, tested and works good. Also there is no need to write a new lib, a lot of work already done with existed libs, though not done, yet. That's how free and open source software should be developed if possible. I'm not interested in developing for .net/mono at the moment, but if someone wants to develop a telegram client lib, one should take a better look at what it is already done and continue developing of it. But if one will say that it is too hard to understand the undone lib, or it has a not good design, then it is OK.

Comment: @AlexanderLogger good points, but the thing is, most libs might be older Telegram layers, maybe just up to 23. The current API is on layer 48... Knowing how to write your own TL parser etc enables you update your lib as required. You may build of course on other OSS work if you must. But just as you pointed out, there are libs out there frozen and incomplete, or out of date

Comment: @CharlesO actually layer system is an independent part based upon core protocol which stays the same, hence almost all implemented things are not outdated (at least SharpTL and SharpMTProto), only supported layer of the API, which can easily updated from current layer json with a special tool: SharpTL.Compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at this C# telegram Library instead: https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp

Also you might want to get started on learning their API and building your own library from scratch.

Here are some notes to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080

Cheers

Comment: TLSharp is no longer supported/maintained

Answer (score 2):

There is now [WTelegramClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WTelegramClient/), using the latest Telegram Client API protocol (connecting as a user, not bot).

The library is very complete but also very easy to use. Follow the [README on GitHub](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient#readme) for an easy introduction.

To send a message to someone can be as simple as:

```cs
using TL;

using var client = new WTelegram.Client(); // or Client(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable)
await client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
var result = await client.Contacts_ImportContacts(new[] { new InputPhoneContact { phone = "+PHONENUMBER" } });
await client.SendMessageAsync(result.users[result.imported[0].user_id], "Hello");

//or by username:
//var result = await client.Contacts_ResolveUsername("USERNAME");
//await await client.SendMessageAsync(result.User, "Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

With C# telegram Library at https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp
TLSharpTests.cs contains examples:

```
    public async Task ImportContactByPhoneNumberAndSendMessage()
    {
        // User should be already authenticated!

        var store = new FileSessionStore();
        var client = new TelegramClient(store, "session");
        await client.Connect();

        Assert.IsTrue(client.IsUserAuthorized());

        var res = await client.ImportContactByPhoneNumber(NumberToSendMessage);

        Assert.IsNotNull(res);

        await client.SendMessage(res.Value, "Test message from TelegramClient");
    }
```