# Telegram Api TLSharp

Tags: c#, api, telegram

Greeting
Export problem of program Tlsharp!
I'm using Tlsharp source messaging app telegram via api's not true.
It was the most perfect program if I am wrong I'm grateful that you introduced.
I did everything I could run this program and I'm grateful I was to say to me how to run it run exe output you got to practice his education and got replaced but could not get API_HASH API_ID and export-execute Knm.ltfa me thanks
https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have api_id and api_hash

you must sign in in Telegram Site in this address

https://my.telegram.org/auth

Type your phoneNumber and click Next

you will receive Verification Code by SMS Or your Telegram app

Type received verification code there and click sign in and follow the site

After doing this, you have api_id and api_hash


Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 0):

See an explanation of he steps to follow here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34929980/44080