# Where I can find telegram api for UWP

Tags: c#, api, win-universal-app, telegram

Have anyone know link to telegram api for universal windows platform (UWP). I can't use telegram api library on C# as https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp, because it built on .Net framework 4.5, if I will recompile project on portable library - I have to refactor code, because some classes doesn't exist in .Net core for UWP. Also I don't want using telegram bot api because I try to code telegram client.

Comment: have you considered writing your own Telegram API code from scratch? Its not that difficult. start here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080

Answer (score 0):

I think [Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot) API is what you're looking for.

Comment: No, bot api and client api have different functions.