# How to send a request to the Telegram API?

Tags: https, tcp, telegram

I have read the documentation here https://core.telegram.org/api.
I want to use API (not bot).
I created an application and received `api_id`, `api_hash`, Test configuration (`ip` and `port`), Production configuration (IP and port) and Public keys.
This is all methods https://core.telegram.org/methods. I want use method `auth.checkPhone`,
but I do not understand how to send a request.

Headers should be such as:

```
POST /apiw1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 000.000.000.000:443 //Production configuration
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: ...
Origin: ...
User-Agent: ...
Accept: */*
Referer: ...
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

But the data is encoded by MTProto.

From documentation written:

```
auth.checkedPhone#e300cc3b phone_registered:Bool phone_invited:Bool = auth.CheckedPhone;
---functions---
auth.checkPhone#6fe51dfb phone_number:string = auth.CheckedPhone;
```

Please tell me step by step how to encode data from this method `auth.checkPhone`. And how to get the Authorization Key? I read the documentation, but I do not understand. Tell me the logic please, the code I will write itself on PHP.

Comment: You can start here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement authorization using a Telegram API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661644/how-to-implement-authorization-using-a-telegram-api)