# How to send requests to telegram client API using python?

Tags: python, api, telegram

I created my `api_id` ad `api_hash` in https://my.telegram.org/apps. Now I've access to them and I see two IPs and one public key for communicating Telegram Client API. I know how bot API works in there (example: https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/getMe) but I can't figure out How I should send my requests to client API IPs.

`Test configuration: 149.154.167.40:443
Production configuration: 149.154.167.50:443`

I know it's my first step to getting the auth code! but I don't know how to request it! core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode

Comment: start here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080

Comment: Along with Charles' link above, here is a pdf that contains a diagram of the handshaking involved. I find visuals very helpful: https://www.incibe.es/extfrontinteco/img/File/intecocert/EstudiosInformes/INT_Telegram_EN.pdf

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu this vb.net language it's same chinese to me, I glad if you have other languages references ?

Comment: @john.... Elixir maybe :)