# get TELEGRAM GROUP ID (with my USER, without BOT)

Tags: telegram

I dont know why this is so hard?

What is the way to get GROUP ID (to get channel ID i use **Plus+** messenger, but it doesnt show the GROUP ID), where I am a regular member (not an admin),so i cant add bots there.

p.s. If i forward message to external bots, they cant see the Group ID, instead they return the CHAT_ID (that ID is of a chat between me and that bot, thus useless for me).

Comment: do you want to do this via code?

Comment: doesnt matter, any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1) If you are a member of a group, you should receive `updates` from that group when ever there is any activity from that group. The updates will contain a `chats` list-element from which you can get a `Channel` which has the following relevant fields:

```
id: group_id, 
title: "the_group_title", 
username: "group_username"
```

Comment: how can i get updates for my user? As i know, I have to request updates for bots, like `api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getUpdates`, but how can i get updates for my regular user? can you give me more example?

Comment: not for bots, i'm referring to the a simple client written with the Telegram API

Comment: @T.Todua for examples of how to get started on writing your own simple client, take a look at this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080

Comment: Charles, thans for you help, but the last thing is missing to me... you have given Github link, where are tens of other libraries/projects..
can you give me just any (already ready) project/software, which i can use to get `updates` for my user? if you can give me that, I'll check your answer as "chosen".

Comment: @T.Todua my thinking was that you wanted to build your own simple client for this. which language are you comfortable with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151491/discussion-between-charles-okwuagwu-and-t-todua).

Comment: You helped me to find the id. however, i did that using CuteGram app...

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way i found is

- open web-telegram in a browser
- right click on the group name on the left menu
- click 'inspect' button
- you will see the group id in the attribute
  **data-peer-id="-xxxxxxxxxx" or peer="-xxxxxxxxxx"**