# How should I start implementing telegram-mtproto without using any packages in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, telegram

I want to implement the telegram-mtproto using nodejs and create a client nodejs telegram app but I don't know how to do this. the api and protocol part in telegram website make me confused and I didn't understand anything from them.
my starting question is how to create a keppalive connection with telegram server?

Comment: were you able to find a way? I am also wanting to take this route, but reading material is slim on this, wondering if you managed to figure it out, or what approach you ended up taking?

Comment: @user7592671 I worked on it a lot and I learned many things but I can't complete implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to implement authorization using a Telegram API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661644/how-to-implement-authorization-using-a-telegram-api/32809138#32809138) it's the most exhaustive answer that exists on the subject. None of the code is in Node but with some effort you'll be able to translate things.