# How to use mtproto telegram api using curl or postman?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I dont want to use python libraries like `telethon` to interact with telegram MtProto api, instead I want to hit the api directly with http-request like curl or via Postman

The reason is that, the actual api response and the library response for an api call, could be different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start from scratch and interact with mtproto you should start with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080) and also have a look at the [Official docs](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto)