# How to connect mtproto telegram client without library / framework?

Tags: dart, sockets, websocket, telegram, mtproto

I've been looking for a way to make a connection to the telegram api for a long time, but I didn't find anything suitable

i have read this: https://core.telegram.org/mtproto
and this: [How to implement authorization using a Telegram API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661644/how-to-implement-authorization-using-a-telegram-api/32809138#32809138)

But I can't figure out how to decode and encrypt it. I've read other open-source code, but I still don't understand how to port it to the language I'm going to use.

Can you write instructions on how to use the mtproto api telegram on dart? you can write the language you prefer.

I want to use the client on dart language

Comment: If you can't find an existing library/framework to do the job, then you'll have to write your own library/framework and use that.  Either way you'll end up using a library/framework (but the first way is much easier).

Comment: The instructions are already written and they are many pages, that's too much for us to rewrite and anyway who is to say we'd do any better. First of all you should ask a more focused question about a very specific part that you don't understand, and second I'm not sure explaining a protocol is really on-topic here.