# Telegram API (NOT Bot API) on google script

Tags: http, google-apps-script, tcp, telegram

i'm trying to script something on google script to use Telegram API to overcome Bot api limitation (es file size, impossibility to join channels as users do, etc).

I checked TDLib but I think it cannot be ported to google script.
CryptoJS is usable on google script, so I tried to use the last option described here:
https://core.telegram.org/api

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661644/how-to-implement-authorization-using-a-telegram-api/32809138#32809138) I see that the API is based on TCP layer, not HTTP, so urlFetchApp cannot be used, right?

Do you know if there is a way to send / recive TCP packets using google script or a way to use TDLib on google script?

Comment: HTTP(at least till  version 2) runs on TCP. The former is a application protocol, while the latter is a Internet Protocol.

Comment: That's the point, the gscript api allow to use HTTP protocol (over TCP) but from what I understood Telegram API is based on pure TCP packets that's not supported by google script

Comment: You're right. AFAIK, Raw sockets are not accessible. One area of interest would be web assembly/TDLib, as Apps script has wasm support, but I wouldn't be hopeful of having even remote success.